# Changing a function based view to a class based view

Tags: django, class, django-views

How would one change this function based view into a class based view? It represents a post view with a comments section.

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
is_liked = False
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    is_liked = True

if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
        comment.save()
        resp = post.get_absolute_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(resp)
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

context = {
    'post': post,
    'is_liked': is_liked,
    'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
    'comments': comments,
    'comment_form': comment_form
}

return render(request, 'feed/post_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: You might find [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#avoid-anything-more-complex) useful. Or you could start with a `CreateView` and override `get_context_data` to add info about the post. Note that a class-based-view isn't necessarily better. If the function based view works and you understand it, then why not stick with it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in this case? If it's just as an exercise, you have two options to start here: Either you see this as a `CreateView` for a `Comment` (and add the `post` data) or you see it as a `DetailView` for a `Post` and add all the comment posting stuff. Either way, it might not become more easy to understand than the function view you have now.

Comment: Note that you should normally use `form.cleaned_data` instead of `request.POST` to get data from the form. And if it's a model form, you should be able to call `form.save()` to create the comment instead of `Comment.objects.create()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic view for this.

```
from django.views.generic import View

class PostDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
         post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
         comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
         is_liked = False
         if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
             is_liked = True

         comment_form = CommentForm()

         context = {
             'post': post,
             'is_liked': is_liked,
             'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
             'comments': comments,
             'comment_form': comment_form
         }

         return render(request, 'feed/post_detail.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
            comment.save()
            resp = post.get_absolute_url()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(resp)
```